# return list of list on c# from IronScheme

Tags: c#, scheme, ironscheme

I want return a list in Visual Studio but, only print `IronScheme.Runtime.Cons` on visual studio console.

I have this code

```
    public void f1()
        {
            var exp = "(car '((1 (8 7 2) 3) 4 5 6))"; // this must eval as "(1 (8 7 2) 3)"
            var result = exp.Eval<Cons>(); 

            var list = result.Cast<string>().ToList();

          /*  foreach(string value in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list);
            }
          */
        }
```

the above code show `System.InvalidCastException`, I want return the list as a string like a:
 `"(1 (8 7 2) 3)"` or a `List<string>`, but this dont work :(

Answer (score 0):

The schemish way :)

```
var exp = "(car '((1 (8 7 2) 3) 4 5 6))";
var result = "(format \"~a\" {0})".Eval<string>(exp);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```